# Функция за функцией php

Tags: php, функции

Каждая следующая функция зависит от предыдущей, если if'ы не писать, между ними, то будет ли корректно работать?

Например, вторая функция запустится после выполнения первой или одновременно начнут все сразу?

```
<?

function one ();
function two ();
function three ();

?>
```

Comment: Да будет все выполнено последовательно. И `<?php` используйте такой тег для открытия php так как тег `<?` может быть не включен. Так же тег `?>` не рекомендуют использовать вообще

Comment: Вы объявили функции, а чтоб они выполнялись нужно их вызвать, например как в ответе ниже, правда функции объявляются так `function name(){...};`

Comment: Ага, готовые скрипты внутри функции есть, мне лишь их вызвать последовательно и все, спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не начнут.

Но если функции зависят одна от другой, то они должны передавтаь друг другу данные

```
<?php

$data = one ();
$data = two ($data);
$data = three ($data);
```

Comment: Если функции `void` достаточно обвернуть в `try { } catch(Exception $e) {}` и выбрасывать exception в случае неудачи в одной из функции

Comment: @Naumov Если функции void, то они не связаны друг с другом.

Comment: Ну кук процедуру, мне для начала надо выполнить одну процедуру, потом другую.

Answer (score 0):

Вы объявили функции, а чтоб они выполнялись нужно их вызвать, например как в ответе от [Ипатьев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1087310/297355), либо так, если нужно простое выполнение функции без передачи аргументов в неё

```
$result = one(); 
$result = two(); 
$result = three();
```

Функции будут выполняться в том порядке, в котором вы их вызываете